# submit form along with request parameter

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-frontend

i want to use javascript to submit my form to the backend. However, I have to add a variable parameter to the form url/action endpoint as well. Wondering what the javascript way of doing this is?

This is what i have now

```
<form id="profile-message-form" action="/send-message?to" method="get">
   <textarea name="message-content" id="message-content" maxlength="1000" contentEditable="true"></textarea>
   <div id="send-button-container">
       <button id="profile-message-submit" onclick="sendMessage('profile-message-form')" name="subject" type="submit"><i id="profile-message-send-icon" class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i><p>Send</p></button>
   </div>
</form>

function sendMessage(form_id) {
    var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    // find email address to send to
    // submit form with email address as ":to" req param
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the email address from?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add hidden fields to form before submitting it.

```js
const formEl = document.getElementById('form');

formEl.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const hiddenAgeEl = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenAgeEl.type = 'hidden';
  hiddenAgeEl.name = 'age';
  hiddenAgeEl.value = 22;
  
  formEl.append(hiddenAgeEl);
  
  formEl.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/send-message?to" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: tried this and for some reason now when i parse req.body at the backend it is empty. reverted the changes and its still empty oddly. it only fixed when i changed the form method to post instead of get

Comment: @masterghani, can't tell for sure, but look in direction of Content-Type. Most likely that your server is configured to get data in `content-type: application/json`, and we are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default